# cakePHP Validations : one model for to forms in the same view

Tags: validation, model, cakephp-2.0

I have one view wich has 2 forms one for login and one for registration as following :
signup.ctp //my view

```
    <div>
     <?php 
       echo $this->Form->create("Tbluser"); 
       echo $this->Form->hidden('formsent', array('value' => 'signup'));
       echo $this->Form->input('username' ,array('label'=>'Username')); 
       echo $this->Form->input('password' ,array('label'=>'Password','type' => 'password')); 
       echo $this->Form->input('email' ,array('label'=>'Email'));
       echo $this->Form->end('Register');
     ?> 
    </div>

<div>
 <?php 
    echo $this->Form->create("Tbluser");  ?>
    echo $this->Form->hidden('formsent', array('value' => 'login')); 
    echo $this->Form->input('username' ,array('label'=>"Username :"));
    echo $this->Form->input('password' ,array('label'=>"Password :",'type' => 'password'));
    echo $this->Form->end('Login'); 
 ?>
<div>
```

The model I'm using for both forms is as following :

```
<?php
class Tbluser extends AppModel{

    public $validate = array(
        'username'=>array(
            array(
                'rule'=>'alphaNumeric',
                'allowEmpty'=>false,
                'message'=>'Invalide Username!'
            ),
            array(
                'rule' => array('minLength', '4'),
                'message' => 'Username has to be more than 3 chars'
            ),
            array(
                'rule'=>'isUnique',
                'message'=>'Username already taken!'
            )
        ),
        'password' => array(
                array(
                    'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
                    'allowEmpty'=>false,
                    'message' => 'Password must be AlphaNumeric!'
                ),
                array(
                    'rule' => array('minLength', '4'),
                    'message' => 'Username has to be more that 3 chars'
                )
            ),
        'email'=>array(
            array(
                'rule'=>array('email',true),
                'required'=>true,
                'allowEmpty'=>false,
                'message'=>'Invalide email adress!'
            ),
            array(
                'rule'=>'isUnique',
                'message'=>'Mail adress already taken!'
            )
        )
    );
}
?>
```

The controller I'm using is as following :

```
<?php
class TblusersController extends AppController
{
    public $uses = array(
        'Tbluser'
    );

    public function signup()
    {
      if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ('signup' === $this->request->data['Tbluser']['formsent']) {
                         // Registration part.
                }else if('login' === $this->request->data['Tbluser']['formsent']){
                         //Login part
                }
    }
}
?>
```

My AppController looks like :

```
<?php
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $helpers = array('Form', 'Html');
    public $components = array('Session','Cookie','Auth'=>array(
        'authenticate'=>array(
             'Form' => array(
                'userModel' => 'Tblforumuser',
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'username',
                    'password' => 'password'
                )
            )
        )
    ));
}
?>
```

Right now if I fill wrong data into the signup form and submit it the validation occurs but also in the login form fields so How can I set the validation only to apply to that signup form and not to both forms? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all validation is being invoked on every read and write because you are telling your model to run all validation without restriction.  A better way to handle this would be a separate model for each form.

By creating two new models `userLogin` and `userRegister` that extend `Tbluser`, you can set specific validation rules for each form.  You could do something like :

*View/Tbluser/signup.ctp*

```
<div>
 <?php 
   echo $this->Form->create("userRegister"); 
   echo $this->Form->hidden('formsent', array('value' => 'signup'));
   echo $this->Form->input('username' ,array('label'=>'Username')); 
   echo $this->Form->input('password' ,array('label'=>'Password','type' => 'password')); 
   echo $this->Form->input('email' ,array('label'=>'Email'));
   echo $this->Form->end('Register');
 ?> 
</div>

<div>
 <?php 
    echo $this->Form->create("userLogin");  ?>
    echo $this->Form->hidden('formsent', array('value' => 'login')); 
    echo $this->Form->input('username' ,array('label'=>"Username :"));
    echo $this->Form->input('password' ,array('label'=>"Password :",'type' => 'password'));
    echo $this->Form->end('Login'); 
 ?>
<div>
```

Here, since we're using two separate models with each `$this->Form-create();` helper, only the validation in the specified model will be run.  Your models will contain only the validation that applies to the form assigned to it:

*Model/userRegister.php*

```
class userRegister extends Tbluser{
    public $validate = array(
        'username'=>array(
            array(
                'rule'=>'alphaNumeric',
                'allowEmpty'=>false,
                'message'=>'Invalide Username!'
            ),
            array(
                'rule' => array('minLength', '4'),
                'message' => 'Username has to be more than 3 chars'
            ),
            array(
                'rule'=>'isUnique',
                'message'=>'Username already taken!'
            )
        ),
        'password' => array(
                array(
                    'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
                    'allowEmpty'=>false,
                    'message' => 'Password must be AlphaNumeric!'
                ),
                array(
                    'rule' => array('minLength', '4'),
                    'message' => 'Username has to be more that 3 chars'
                )
            ),
        'email'=>array(
            array(
                'rule'=>array('email',true),
                'required'=>true,
                'allowEmpty'=>false,
                'message'=>'Invalide email adress!'
            ),
            array(
                'rule'=>'isUnique',
                'message'=>'Mail adress already taken!'
            )
        )
    );
}
```

*Model/userLogin.php*

```
class userLogin extends Tbluser{
    public $validate = array(
        'username'=>array(
            array(
                'rule'=>'alphaNumeric',
                'allowEmpty'=>false,
                'message'=>'Invalide Username!'
            ),
            array(
                'rule' => array('minLength', '4'),
                'message' => 'Username has to be more than 3 chars'
            ),
            array(
                'rule'=>'isUnique',
                'message'=>'Username already taken!'
            )
        ),
        'password' => array(
            array(
                'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
                'allowEmpty'=>false,
                'message' => 'Password must be AlphaNumeric!'
            ),
            array(
                'rule' => array('minLength', '4'),
                'message' => 'Username has to be more that 3 chars'
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Then in your `signup();` method, you will want to load the two new models you just created accordingly:

*Controller/TblusersController.php*

```
class TblusersController extends AppController {
    public $uses = array(
        'Tblforumuser'
    );

    public function signup() {
      $this->loadModel('userLogin');
      $this->loadModel('userRegistration'); 
      if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ('signup' === $this->request->data['Tblforumuser']['formsent']) {
                         // Registration part.
                }else if('login' === $this->request->data['Tblforumuser']['formsent']){
                         //Login part
                }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, I tested your solution however I get the following error : Error: Class 'Tbluser' not found
File: /var/www/pttlk/app/Model/userRegistration.php
Line: 2

Comment: Since you are extending Tbluser, it needs to exists.  To keep all of the automagic intact, you need to extend the model of the table used by TbluserController which is Tbluser in your case.